# Geany IDE backup copy path

Tags: ide, geany

I just lost an entire script in Geany editor...
Is there a place where Geany saves a backup or cached copy somewhere?

Thank you for your help...

Comment: often such files are prepended with a ~ (tilde symbol) and will hang about fir a while.  use "ls -al" or other means to see hidden files in your working directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geany does not automatically create backup files unless you enable the "Save Actions" plugin, and select "Auto Save".

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what do you want. Geany *can* save a backup copy of the unedited file and also various options of saving the edit buffer. Read this nice wiki [All you never wanted to know about file saving](http://wiki.geany.org/config/all_you_never_wanted_to_know_about_file_saving).

Comment: Yes, a lovely must-read ( better before one's first major crash -- 've lost 80k SLOCs, trimmed to a 0 B file, just due to a mysterious fileIO -- so indeed **worth taking more precautions ... you never wanted to know about file saving** :o)  )

Answer (score 0):

To backup scripts, use [GitHub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Github).

There are other VCS's (Version Control System), but Git has a strong feature set and is fairly easy to use.  The real strength of Git, to my mind, is GitHub, which, so far as I know, is the only free-as-in-beer site which will let you create a large number of projects.  It also seems to be well run, and I find many API's I like on that site.

Use VCS to:

1.)  backup your code so that you don't lose it
1a.) backup offsite, such as to github in the event of your computer bursting into flames
2.)  keep track of different versions, comments, etc
3.)  collaborate!  Give your code to the community.  Or, fork someone elses code.

The caveat to all this is to omit passwords or other sensitive files.  Don't upload a file with your credentials for logging into e-mail, for example.  RTFM to see how to omit specific files with Git.

Finally, if you don't like Git there are alternatives, SVN has, in some scenarios, better syntax.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you have just overwritten the file (Ctrl+S) and haven't yet quit Geany, you can just Ctrl+Z to the desired document state and save that file version.
2. If you have already quit Geany after that and haven't set up back up in Geany before, I am afraid that by means of Geany you cannot restore the file to the previous state.
3. Read [this article](https://wiki.geany.org/config/all_you_never_wanted_to_know_about_file_saving) about how to set up back up in Geany. Basically you can go to Edit -> Preferences -> Various (read [the manual](https://www.geany.org/manual/current/index.html) and the link above before changing these preferences) and:

   1. disable `use_atomic_file_saving` (***disabled*** by default)
   2. enable `use_gio_unsafe_file_saving` (***enabled*** by default)
   3. enable `gio_unsafe_save_backup` (***disabled*** by default)

This will always keep the **previous version of the file (as a hidden file with `~` attached to its name**) next to original.

Or you can install/enable the **Save Actions** Geany plugin and enable the **Auto Save** and **Backup Copy** options to automatically save files at a certain time interval and to keep a copy of previous file versions.